# If I can define a function in terms of foldl, would it make it tail recursive?

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming, tail-recursion

I was given an assignment in my functional programming course that asks me to rewrite several functions, like `map` and `filter` to be tail recursive.

I'm not 100% sure how to go about this yet but I know that you can define functions by calling `foldr` and `foldl`. I know `foldl` is tail recursive, so if I can define say, `filter` with `foldl`, would it become tail recursive, too?

Comment: That's quite a strange assignment. You would never want `map` or `filter` to be tail recursive in Haskell!

Comment: As for your question, I think you'd best write it out by hand to satisfy your teacher--using `foldl` might seem like a cop-out.

Comment: @dfeuer: I might just be tired, but I'm not seeing it: why _you would never want `map` or `filter` to be tail recursive_...?

Comment: @ErikAllik, you lose spine laziness, which makes the functions less useful while also (for long lists) slowing them down.

Comment: so you mean tail recursion as opposed to what?

Comment: @ErikAllik as opposed to [guarded recursion](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2007/07/data-and-codata.html). Note that `map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs` is not tail recursive

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways to make a recursive function tail recursive:

1. Convert the function to accumulator passing style. This only works in some cases.
2. Convert the function to continuation passing style. This works in all cases.

Consider the definition of the `map` function:

```hs
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map _ []     = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

In accumulator passing style, we have an additional argument which accumulates the result:

```hs
mapA :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b] -> [b]
mapA _ []     = id
mapA f (x:xs) = mapA f xs . (f x :)
```

The original `map` function can be recovered as follows:

```hs
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f xs = reverse $ mapA f xs []
```

Note that we need to `reverse` the result. This is because `mapA` accumulates the result in reverse:

```hs
> mapA (+1) [1,2,3,4,5] []
> mapA (+1) [2,3,4,5]  [2]
> mapA (+1) [3,4,5]  [3,2]
> mapA (+1) [3,5]  [4,3,2]
> mapA (+1) [5]  [5,4,3,2]
> mapA (+1) [] [6,5,4,3,2]
> [6,5,4,3,2]
```

Now, consider continuation passing style:

```hs
mapK :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> ([b] -> r) -> r
mapK _ []     k = k []
mapK f (x:xs) k = mapK f xs (k . (f x :))
```

The original `map` function can be recovered as follows:

```hs
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f xs = mapK f xs id
```

Note that we do not need to `reverse` the result. This is because although `mapK` accumulates the continuations in reverse, yet when finally applied to the base case the continuations are unfolded to produce the result in the correct order:

```hs
> mapK (+1) [1,2,3,4,5] id
> mapK (+1) [2,3,4,5]  (id . (2:))
> mapK (+1) [3,4,5]    (id . (2:) . (3:))
> mapK (+1) [4,5]      (id . (2:) . (3:) . (4:))
> mapK (+1) [5]        (id . (2:) . (3:) . (4:) . (5:))
> mapK (+1) []         (id . (2:) . (3:) . (4:) . (5:) . (6:))
> (id . (2:) . (3:) . (4:) . (5:) . (6:)) []
> (id . (2:) . (3:) . (4:) . (5:))       [6]
> (id . (2:) . (3:) . (4:))            [5,6]
> (id . (2:) . (3:))                 [4,5,6]
> (id . (2:))                      [3,4,5,6]
>  id                            [2,3,4,5,6]
> [2,3,4,5,6]
```

Note, that in both cases we're doing twice the required amount of work:

1. First, we accumulate an intermediate result in reverse order.
2. Next, we produce the final result in the correct order.

Some functions can be written efficiently in the accumulator passing style (e.g. the `sum` function):

```hs
sumA :: Num a => [a] -> a -> a
sumA []     = id
sumA (x:xs) = sumA xs . (+ x)
```

The original `sum` function can be recovered as follows:

```hs
sum :: Num a => [a] -> a
sum xs = sumA xs 0
```

Note that we don't need to do any post processing on the result.

However, list functions written in tail recursive style always need to be reversed. Hence, we do not write list functions in tail recursive style. Instead, we depend upon laziness to process only as much of the list as required.

It should be noted that continuation passing style is just a special case of accumulator passing style. Since `foldl` is both tail recursive and uses an accumulator, you can write `mapA` and `mapK` using `foldl` as follows:

```hs
mapA :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b] -> [b]
mapA f xs acc = foldl (\xs x -> f x : xs) acc xs

mapK :: ([b] -> r) -> (a -> b) -> [a] -> r
mapK k f xs = foldl (\k x xs -> k (f x : xs)) k xs []
```

For, `mapK` if you take the `k` to be `id` then you get `map`:

```hs
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f xs = foldl (\k x xs -> k (f x : xs)) id xs []
```

Similarly, for `filter`:

```hs
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter p xs = foldl (\k x xs -> k (if p x then x : xs else xs)) id xs []
```

There you have it, tail recursive `map` and `filter` functions. However, don't forget that they are actually doing twice the work. In addition, they won't work for infinite lists because the result will not be generated until the end of the list is reached (which will never happen for infinite lists).

Answer (score 2):

I'm suspecting the professor/lecturer is expecting solutions where tail recursion is used "directly", i.e. lexically, within the source code of the function, not indirectly, or "dynamically", where tail recursion only happens at runtime within the scope of some subroutine call.

Otherwise, you might as well supply e.g. `Prelude.foldl` as the implementation for a custom `foldl` of yours, since it, possibly, uses tail recursion under the hood, and thus does yours:

```
import Prelude as P

foldl = P.foldl
```

but obviously something like that wouldn't be accepted.